# Can you interrupt the vba code to make a sheet selection?

Tags: vba, excel

*I will try to be as clear as possible in the description, so here goes nothing:*

I have created a code in which the user selects his excel file and then the macro copies the `Sheet` from that file into my macro `Workbook`.

```
MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=wbook.Sheets(1)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Selected file"
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

This is working, but what I realized is, that there might be cases where the selected file has multiple `Sheets`.

Is there a way to write the macro in which if my selected file has 1 sheet it runs the above code and if it has more than one sheet to let me select the sheet I want and then run the rest of the code?

Comment: I added an alternative solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52532092/8112776), maybe more like what you had in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Edit:

- I thought of another way to handle this — perhaps closer to what you were looking for . . .

  [image: img]

It's just an expansion of the basic ***pause*** routine that I use occasionally.

This is my **"regular" `Pause` routine** (using the [`Timer` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function)):

```vb
Sub Pause(seconds As Single)
    Dim startTime As Single
    startTime = Timer                          'get current timer count
    Do
        DoEvents                               'let Windows "catch up"
    Loop Until Timer > startTime + seconds     'repeat until time's up
End Sub
```

...so, it gave me an idea.

Honestly, I was a little surprised to discover that this works, since it's basically *running two sections of code simultaneously*.

---

### Code for `WaitForUserActivity` :

Here's the code I used in the demo above:

```vb
Option Explicit
Public isPaused As Boolean

Sub WaitForUserActivity()                   'THE 'RUN DEMO' BUTTON runs this sub.

    Dim origSheet As String
    isPaused = True                                   'flag "pause mode" as "on"
    origSheet = ActiveSheet.Name                'remember current worksheet name

    MsgBox "This will 'pause' code execution until you" & vbLf & _
           "click the 'Continue' button, or select a different a worksheet."
    Application.StatusBar = "PAUSED: Click ""Continue"", or select a worksheet."

    Do                                       'wait for button click or ws change
        DoEvents        'yield execution so that the OS can process other events
    Loop Until (Not isPaused) Or (ActiveSheet.Name <> origSheet)

    If isPaused Then                           'the active worksheet was changed
        MsgBox "Worksheet '" & ActiveSheet.Name & "' was selected." _
              & vbLf & vbLf & "Now the program can continue..."
    Else                                                 'the button was clicked
        MsgBox "The 'Continue' button was clicked." _
              & vbLf & vbLf & "Now the program can continue..."
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = "Ready"
End Sub

Sub btnContinue()                          'THE 'CONTINUE' BUTTON runs this sub.
    isPaused = False                                 'flag "pause mode" as "off"
End Sub
```

**To run the demo**:

- place the above code in a regular module
- make sure the workbook has at least two worksheets
- create two command buttons:

  - one for the "**Run Demo**" button, assign macro: `WaitForUserActivity`
  - one for the "**Continue**" button, assign macro: `btnContinue`
- click the "**Run Demo**" button

---

The key command in the code is the [`DoEvents` Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function), which "yields execution so that the operating system can process other events."

> `DoEvents` passes control to the operating system. Control is returned after the operating system has finished processing the events in its queue and all keys in the SendKeys queue have been sent.
>
> `DoEvents` is most useful for simple things like allowing a user to cancel a process after it has started, for example a search for a file. For long-running processes, yielding the processor is better accomplished by using a Timer or delegating the task to an `ActiveX` [`EXE`](https://www.tutorialsweb.com/activex/standard-and-activex-projects.htm) component - and the operating system takes care of multitasking and [time slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice).
>
> Any time you temporarily yield the processor within an event procedure, **make sure the procedure is not executed again from a different part of your code before the first call returns**; this could cause unpredictable results.
>
> Further details (and warnings) at the [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function).

---

---

### Original Answer:

Some suggested solutions:

1. Instead of "stopping" the code you could **prompt the user** to specify which worksheet.

   - The easiest way would be with an [`InputBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) where the user would enter an ID number or otherwise identify the worksheet.
   - More complicated but more robust and professional-looking would be a custom dialog box with the help of a userform. There are several examples and tutorials online such as [this one](http://what-when-how.com/excel-vba/excel-vba-custom-dialog-box-basics/).
2. You could **"pause" execution** to give the user a set amount of time to select a worksheet, with a simple **timer loop**, ad you could even check the worksheet name to see if the user picked a new one, something like this:

   ```vb
   Dim startTime As Single, shtName As String
   If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count = 1 Then
       MsgBox "There is only one worksheet in this workbook."
   Else
       shtName = ActiveSheet.Name 'get name of active sheet
       MsgBox "You have 5 seconds to select a worksheet after clicking OK.", _
           vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Select a worksheet... fast!"
       startTime = Timer
       Do
           DoEvents
       Loop Until Timer > startTime + 5

       'check if user picked a new worksheet
       If ActiveSheet.Name = shtName Then
           MsgBox "You didn't select a new worksheet!"
       Else
           MsgBox "Thanks for selecting a new worksheet!"
       End If
   End If
   ```

   It's a little hoakey but could work, especially if proper checks to make sure you've got the correct worksheet now.
3. I suppose you could create an **worksheet event procedure** that would run when a worksheet is activated, and checked a global variable to see if your "import procedure" *was* running, and if so, *resume* your code... but that would be messy and confusing and would require the code to exist in the workbook you're "importing".
4. Or, *better than any of those* would be to programmatically/**logically determine which worksheet you need** based on the contents of the worksheet.  Is there a title?  A certain date?  Maybe the newest worksheet?  Something in a certain cell? There must be something that differentiates it from the others.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas towards a *non-linear* solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestions. Your suggestion 1.1 is the one RawrPlus added the code below and it seemed like the best solution for me. Option 2, I didn't want to create a time pressure for the user. Option 3, the workbook I'm importing will always be a new one so it doesn't seem feasible to have code in that one as well. And for option 3, the contents of the worksheet will always be in the same structure (nr of rows and columns might differ but it is all basically the same type of data) and the sheet names are something like "1_1", "1_2" so I don't think that would work either.

Answer (score 1):

> As in whole, I would recommend ashleedawg's solution, but if you
>   insisted on maintaining your code structure, your code could look
>   something like this:

You can distinguish between amount of Sheets a Workbook has using `.Count` property of the `Sheets` object *(or `Worksheets` if you do not want to include `Chart`s)* and use `InputBox` to check for the sheet you want to look for.

```
MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Workbooks.Open (MyFile)

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count = 1 Then
  ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=wbook.Sheets(1)
  ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Selected File"
Else
  Dim checkfor As String
  checkfor = InputBox("What Sheet should I execute the code for?")

  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
     If Trim(LCase(checkfor)) = Trim(LCase(Sheets(i).Name))) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Copy After := wbook.Sheets(1)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = "Selected file"
     End If
  Next i
End If

Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Might need some further tweaking, because I was unsure what exactly you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the code suggestion. I did updated it in a few parts for what I wanted

Comment: @Andreea  glad it helped, mark either mine or ashlee's answer as the solution then please, so the question can be considered as closed :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I went with ashlee's answer in the end. After testing the macro on multiple files. It didn't seem to work in all situations for some reason.